# Bookmarking remote directories (tramp+sudo)

Tags: tramp, bookmarks

I have to connect to remote computers through ssh. I'm using tramp (`C-x d /sshx:user@myhost|su:myhost:/mydirectory`) and I can sudo as root on directories in this machine. As it is very convenient, I would like to bookmark the location.

After giving a name to the bookmark, I can see that my latest bookmark looks like `'my newbookmark    /su:root@myhost:/mydirectory'`, therefore forgetting the first half of the location. And when I try to comeback to it (after closing emacs for example), I have a message `"Host 'myhost' looks like a remote host, 'su' can only use the local host"`.

How would it be possible to bookmark the whole location?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know whether it is possible to bookmark the whole remote path as you type it. But please be aware, that the pipe notation `/sshx:user@myhost|su:myhost:` is called ad-hoc proxies, it is not intended to survive an Emacs session. I recommend you to add the proxy configuration in your `.emacs` file, as described in the Tramp manual:

```
(add-to-list 'tramp-default-proxies-alist
             '("\\`mydomain\\'" "\\`root\\'" "/sshx:user@%h:"))
```

From now on, you could always use `/su:myhost:` as remote identification.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Even if I have a lot of hosts to connect, this works as stated in the documentation. For future reference, look at  https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/tramp/Multi_002dhops.html (and search for Ubuntu). I was afraid at first I would have to do it for every single host, which might have been rather painful.

Comment: The variable tramp-save-ad-hoc-proxies (https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/tramp/Ad_002dhoc-multi_002dhops.html) could come in handy too.